# Apache pig Store based on condition

Tags: apache-pig

I'm reading from a csv file and after grouping those datas I'm doing a count operation . Is there any way to store the datas into a folder name bad if the count is 0 and to good if the count is > 0 . I tried with the below code but it is not happening .

```
CODE : 

STORE countVal INTO '/user/cloudera/good' IF countVal > 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

USE function SPLIT.  Refer :

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT

```
SPLIT A INTO X IF f1<7, Y IF f2==5, Z IF (f3<6 OR f3>6);
```

Comment: If i do like that then every time two folder getting created . But I want that if countValue is 0 then the entire file will be stored into bad folder otherwise into good folder . That means when I'm running it once , either good folder is created or bad .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways this :

1)Use the split function to perform the split based on the criteria.

SPLIT data into good if count>0, bad if (count==0);

2)Use a FOREACH loop to separate the data based on a criteria, using a BinCond operator.

X = FOREACH A GENERATE , data, (count>0?"good":"bad");

Comment: I've two folders good and bad , how will I store using BinCond operator ? I've to move the entire file if count > 0 to "good" folder otherwise i have to move the entire file to "bad" folder .